# Elasticsearch aggregation order same as search result

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to perform a search request and only receive unique fields from the documents, ordered by a specific field.
In my case I want the result ordered by a timestamp and I only need the field *refId*. To get only the ids, I use aggregation.

Example of the request from the Elastic Dev Tools

```
POST /MY-INDEX/_search
{
  "size": 0
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      //my query
    }
  },
    "sort" : [
    { "timestamp": {"order" : "asc"}}
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "agg_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "refId"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, the order of the aggregation does not match the order of the search results. Is there possibility to have the same order for aggregations?

---- UPDATE ----
**Example of data**

```
{
  "timestamp": 1604582511657,
  "id": 4
  "refID": "ref3"
}
{
  "timestamp": 1604582511655,
  "id": 3
  "refID": "ref1"
}
{
  "timestamp": 1604582511654,
  "id": 2
  "refID": "ref1"
}
{
  "timestamp": 1604582511653,
  "id": 1
  "refID": "ref2"
}
```

**Search Result**

```
"aggregations": {
    "unique_id": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "ref1",
          "doc_count": 2,
        },
        {
          "key": "ref2",
          "doc_count": 1,
        },
        {
          "key": "ref3",
          "doc_count": 1,
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Expected Result:

```
 "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "ref2",
          "doc_count": 2,
        },
        {
          "key": "ref1",
          "doc_count": 1,
        },
        {
          "key": "ref3",
          "doc_count": 1,
        }
      ]
```

The aggregations result is ordered by doc_count, but not like the search query by the timestamp

Comment: can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Comment: @Bhavya added an example for data and result

Comment: Based on your example data the `doc_count` for `"refID": "ref1"` is 2, how come you are showing `doc_count` for `"refID": "ref2"` as 2 ?

Comment: can you please share your expected search result as well ?

Comment: Sorry this was a copy and paste error. 
Thank you for your solution, it is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) along with [max aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) to achieve your required use case

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "timestamp": 1604582511657,
  "id": 4
  "refID": "ref3"
}
{
  "timestamp": 1604582511656,
  "id": 3
  "refID": "ref1"
}
{
  "timestamp": 1604582511654,
  "id": 2
  "refID": "ref1"
}
{
  "timestamp": 1604582511655,
  "id": 1
  "refID": "ref2"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
  {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "refID.keyword",
        "order": {
          "latestOrder": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latestOrder": {
          "max": {
            "field": "timestamp"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "unique_id": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "ref3",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "latestOrder": {
            "value": 1.604582511657E12
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ref1",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "latestOrder": {
            "value": 1.604582511656E12
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ref2",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "latestOrder": {
            "value": 1.604582511655E12
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: @Clemens please go through my answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?